# Linux command to know system configuration

Tags: linux

I have only hostname of the system like - innpbr.
Does any Linux command exist which can give the system config of this machine?
Like `command <hostname>`

The machine is internal to our network. At least it can tell whether it is a Windows or Linux machine.

Comment: Explain what you mean by *system configuration* and why you are asking.

Comment: I need to run certain linux script  on multiple servers . Before running this script i want to check whether the server is linux or windows .
I have only list of hostnames (servers).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to remotely identify information about a machine (without logging in) you may try using nmap with OS & Version detection.

```
nmap -A 10.0.0.x
```

That'll show you a bunch of information, including operating system and information about services running with network access (like ssh, sql ect.).

Comment: could you suggest any other command , this command is not available in my system and i do not have admin permission for installation .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```
uname -a
```

See [uname(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uname.1.html) for more.

"System configuration" is really vague; perhaps [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) is relevant. Perhaps try the  `lsb_release` command.

Comment: i am not login on the system .